# Start MySQL Server as a service (Win 8)

Tags: mysql, database, service, windows-8, mysql-workbench

I am trying out MySQL (Windows 8), with the workbench (gui) installed as well.

I am still in the installation / configuration process. I would like to create a new database. So, on the workbench's welcome screen, I have selected `New Server Instance- Register a new Server instance to manage`.

In order to do this, I have went through following configuration steps:

1. Specify `localhost` as server host,
2. Give it the username and password I am using.

It then tests a database connection, and, in the next step, asks me to

> Select the Service to manage from the list below.
>   It will also help find the configuration file.

**However, the list of possible Services is empty and if I click [next], it says**

> Error: In Order to manage a MySQL Service it must be installed as a Service. The wizard can not find any MySQL Service at the target machine, so the Server instance cannot be started.

I think that I have to somehow start the MySQL Service, as it might already been installed when I had installed the whole MySQL Toolset.

So: **How would I start this MySQL Service under Windows 8?**

**Some things I've tried:**

The [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-command-line.html) says to try:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld"
```

in order to install it as a Service.  Yet, nothing happens and I get the following (some verbose [Note]s were removed):

```
2013-04-13 23:44:22 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\gast.lower-test
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\gast.lower-test
[...]
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] InnoDB: read can't be opened in .\ibdata1 mode
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [Note] Binlog end
[...]
2013-04-13 23:44:22 2592 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

To install the server as a service, I've used this command ([per the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html)).

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install
```

Again, "nothing" happens, I get (again, most of the verbose [Note]s are removed):

```
Install/Remove of the Service Denied!

c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld -p --install
2013-04-13 23:43:24 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\gast.lower-test
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\gast.lower-test
[...]
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] InnoDB: read can't be opened in .\ibdata1 mode
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '-p'
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [Note] Binlog end
[...]
2013-04-13 23:43:24 3764 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 41):

Type cmd in start and right click and Run as administrator,

then paste the below text in your command prompt,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install
```

If you don't run cmd as Administrator, you'll see `Install/Remove of service denied.`,

So run the elevated command prompt(Start->cmd->Run as Administrator) to see the `Service Successfully installed` message.

[image: Service Denied Screenshot]

***Note***: This is even if you have logged in as administrator in windows 7/8.

If u want to uninstall the service do the following, copy paste the following in command prompt(again elevated command prompt) run this,

`sc delete MySQL`

Here `MySQL` in the command is the service name mysql creates by default in Windows PC. Make sure you see the service is installed in the Services List(Task Manager -> Services Tab -> Check the Mysql service Name column).

[image: Service delete command prompt screenshot]

Comment: 1 upvote for the suggestion of Run as administrator, thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same Problem. I started the Command Prompt in administrator mode and then went to `C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld"` and then just Enter. And it works fine.

**Second way:** While installing the mysql workbench it ask for username and password. By default username is root so if you have set password and still remember it then start MySQL Command Line Client and enter the password and then start the workbench. It will work fine.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hans, first of all, the MySQL installer should install the new server as service already. There's no need for you to do this manually. Look in your services list if you already see the service there. Did you get an error message in the MySQL Installer when it came to server/service installation?

Another point is that the server cannot start up as you can see in the log output. Something is seriously wrong with the InnoDB storage. Did you change the configuration somehow? Keep in mind that MySQL data must not be written in the application folder, but in the application data path. By default the MySQL Installer should also take care of this.

And finally, if you start MySQL Workbench with no connections/server instances it will scan the services to find existing MySQL servers and auto create connections and instances for them.

Answer (score -2):

That's how I install `mysqld`:

```
"e:\denwer\usr\local\mysql-1-5.5\my.ini" --install "mysqld" --defaults-file="e:\denwer\usr\local\mysql-5.5\my.ini"
```

Also I ran command prompt as administrator.