# Fail to start mysql xampp after installing mysqld

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have installed xampp and managed to start up both Apache and MySQL. However, after I've installed MySQL as a service by using [the first answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993089/start-mysql-server-as-a-service-win-8?rq=1), whenever I start MySQL through the XAMPP control panel, it failed. Is there any way to revert the installation of the "mysqld" service or just configure something to make MySQL able to start by XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you install Mysql after you install XAMPP (which already installed Mysql)?? It does not make any sense.

### Options

**1st Option**: uninstall Mysql

**2nd Option**: Stop Mysql services and start XAMPP

**3rd Option**: Change port 3306 to other port (4406)

### Windows (Win7)

1. Windows > Programs and Features > Click on Mysql Server > Uninstall button

[image]

2. Windows > services.msc > Mysql x.x (version) > Stop

[image]

3. Edit my.ini and change port from **3306** to **4406** and Restart Mysql from XAMPP

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however just now I tried uninstalling the damn service but I can't find the service in "Windows Services" and either the server in "Programs". XAMPP fixed itself though now that it can start MySQL as normal. However, in the control panel it says that the service is in the wrong path. ![Here's the link](http://imgur.com/a/m2Rbu#0) plus [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/vA9e79l.jpg). Btw thanks a lot by helping a noob out!

Comment: Any time @AsyraafAinorazahar ! Now that you have your stuff under control, can you please let me know why did you install xampp and mysql later. I saw other users doing the same, and I would like to understand why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. After installing xampp and mysql workbench, when I add a new connection in Workbench, in "Configure Server Management", whenever it tried to find a service, it will fail even with xampp mysql running. So I decided to screw it and just install it manually. Here's the problem, in xampp control panel, it says that expected MySQL path and actual one is different. How do you fix this? Should I just run the xampp installer again to fix it(as it says if the config file is misplaced/whatever)?