# Can't startup and connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to use MySQL Workbench to start a server and connect to it, but for a long time I've been unable to. In the "Startup / Shutdown" tab in the navigator, the log shows

> 2015-07-13 10:05:27 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:28 - Starting server...
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:35 - Server start done.
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Checking server status...
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Assuming server is not running
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Checking server status...
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
>
> 2015-07-13 10:05:36 - Assuming server is not running

Can anyone help me with this or offer an alternate way to run the server and connect to it? Thanks.

OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: What OS are you running?  Have you tried running `service mysqld restart` in the terminal?

Comment: @JPeroutek edited my post, i'm running windows 8.1

Comment: The simplest way to install MySQL server on Windows is to use the [MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/). It installs MySQL in a standard way, enables MySQL as a service by default, creates a my.ini, and can optionally install other applications such as Workbench (GUI) and Notifier (start/stop). It can also upgrade (update) the applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the MySql server running.  You can manually start it by executing something like `shell> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld"` in the command prompt.

If you want to have the server start up automatically, I'd recommend reading [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993089/start-mysql-server-as-a-service-win-8)

More reading on using the MySql server on windows:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: @dragonbanshee Did you try running the command prompt window as an Administrator?

Comment: I did that, and the server opened. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, MySQL was configured as a service to run manually.  To start it I typed "Services" from the Windows 10 Search box.  Then I right-clicked on MySQL80 service and clicked 'Start'.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer somewhere else that I don't remember (so it is not entirely mine) but it worked as a charm (it starts the MySQL server). Open your **Windows terminal** or **cmd** as *Administrator* and enter:

```
net start MySQL80
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is very old, I have wasted around 2 hours and hence want to post this so that it can save someone else's time.

This solution uses the ***window's mysql installer*** which you have used to install your MySQL.

1. Start your windows mysql installer. For me it was "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0"
2. Then remove/uninstall the SQL Server and remove all configurations
3. Manually delete the SQL Server folder from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0."
4. Start your mysql installer again and install the SQL Server again
5. You can check now that the MySqL Server has started.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Lazycoder_007 this helped me! I am new to MySQL as well and was having trouble getting the server to start properly. Originally I did not have the server installed as a Windows service, which I did after the fact. But then I went through your solution which seemed to solve the issue. Also restarted my workstation just to confirm. Thank you!!