# MySQL Workbench Server startup

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having trouble starting up a server through MySQL Workbench. From the navigator pane on the left side of **Instance -> Start/Shutdown**, I tried the "Start Server" button at which point the server will look like it will try to start. The workbench will get hung up at this point and indefinitely not respond with a "thinking" mouse icon while in the workbench app.

This is my first time learning to use MySQL workbench, which I want to say that when I initially installed MySQL Workbench a server did start after installation and worked fine. It was after restarting my computer and checking on the workbench the next day (today) that the server no longer runs. I'm not seeing any MySQL references in my Services (services.msc) that might relate to starting up but that might also be because I did not install as a Windows Service. My original troubleshooting was in trying to establish a connection, which I realized it was because the server wasn't running. Could someone help me understand why the server isn't starting? Or would it be recommended to install the workbench as a Windows Service to avoid the issue I'm having?

[image]
Screenshot of the MySQL Workbench window where the application will get hung up when starting the server.

Current setup: Personal workstation, Windows 10 (64 bit), MySQL Workbench 8.0 (version 8.0.29 build 1751076 CE 64 bits). I do not plan on running the server 24/7 since this is my personal workstation.

Answer (score 5):

1. Right-click on `My Computer`
2. Select `Manage`
3. Select `Services` under `Servies and applications`
4. Find MySQL among the services and open it.
5. Choose `Automatic` as a start option.
6. Click on start.
7. Press Apply & OK then exit.
8. It is not necessary, but I still recommend restarting PC.

Comment: jkalandarov I did install as a Windows service and tried manually starting up the service but will immediately stop right after starting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped

Answer (score 0):

The solution below fixed my issue. I definitely recommend installing MySQL Server as a windows service and making sure uncheck mark the box that says to start when Windows starts unless you plan to have your computer as a dedicated server.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62004033/17996665) from @Lazycoder_007

> This solution uses the window's mysql installer which you have used to
> install your MySQL.
>
> 1. Start your windows mysql installer. For me it was
>    "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0"
> 2. Then remove/uninstall the SQL
>    Server and remove all configurations
> 3. Manually delete the SQL Server
>    folder from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0."
> 4. Start your
>    mysql installer again and install the SQL Server again
> 5. You can check
>    now that the MySqL Server has started.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method**

You can start the MySQL server from the Windows Services interface if you installed MySQL using the MySQL Installer.
Input **services.msc** by pressing **Win + R**, then hit Enter.
Search the list for a service with the name **"MySQL"** or **"MySQL80"** (or a similar name).
To start the server, perform a right-click on the MySQL service and select **"Start"**.
Command Request:

**2nd Method**

As an administrator, launch **Command Prompt**.
Open the MySQL bin directory. Typically, this can be found in the MySQL installation directory, for instance: **bin inside C:Program FilesMySQLMySQL** Server 8.0.
To launch the MySQL server, enter mysqld and press **Enter**.